# UITableView inside Popover

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview, popover

Helo. I have big problem. 
So i have .xib with view (my popover) , tableview and button. 
In popover.m i have just static method to load .xib and close button delegate. Popover is not VC

I have to customize my table and load data from DB.I created 
TableView.m but i cant drag and drop TableView like outlet.
In addition, I implemented delegate/datasource

Have someone similar problem ? :)

I will be grateful for all the advice

Code from popover.

```
+ (TaggingAdditionl *) createInstance {


        TaggingAdditionl *taggingXibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TaggingPopOver" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
         [taggingXibView setFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
         [taggingXibView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


         return  taggingXibView;

}

- (IBAction)didPressCloseButton {

    [self.delegate taggingAdditionDidClose: self];
}


@end
```

Comment: Make sure you are dragging UITableView or UITableViewController in your PopOver View.

Comment: I am dragging into my custom class to UITableView

Comment: Your tableView is inside your PopOver View in .xib file but the problem is you can't make the outlet. Right?

Comment: Yes cuz I load my .xib file in popover.m and i wanted create outlet in tableview.h for customize

Comment: Just Assign that tableView class to tableView in interface builder. Your PopOver View is owner of your TableView as tableView is inside your popOver View. You can't make an outlet of TableView in another class.

Comment: Where should I do : 

-(void)loadData {
    
    self.PlayersTableView.delegate = self;
    self.PlayersTableView.dataSource = self;
    
    self.players = [self.databaseManager.playersDbManager selectAllEntities];
    
    [self.PlayersTableView reloadData];